# change dynamic description meta tag be detectable with search engines in angular 8

Tags: angular, seo, search-engine

I created a website with angular 8.
description's meta's tag have default value.
I get description from backend with api rest and update description's meta's tag with Meta service in home page(main page).

```
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

search engines and analysis tools only detect default value.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem.
I moved change description's meta's tag from home page to `app.components construct`.
search engine detect description's meta's tag now.